# Toad & frog українською

Tags: from-english

Чи правильно буде перекласти українською **frog** як "жаба" а **toad** як "ропуха"?

Comment: А ще ж є [кумки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кумка) та [райки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Райка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, правильно.

- [Toad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_toad) - [Ропуха](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)
- [Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog) - [Жаба](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96)